# Windows 8 Developer licence

Tags: windows-8, license, windows-store, vb.net

I am a Visual Basic.NET programmer, and am wanting to develop apps for the Windows Store. I have just signed up for a developer license and the information box, relating to the license stated that I need to obtain a new license in a months time.

My question is this: Is it free to get a new license in a months time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is free to renew. [More Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx)

Also check out this article regarding [automating renewal](http://michaelcrump.net/renew-your-windows-8-developer-license-before-it-expires)